# Adding table in list of table

Tags: table-of-contents

I want to add table and figure in list of table and figure in latex. Bur the result is not showing properly.

I want the result to be like Figure 1.1 instead of just 1.1. Rest all should be same. I am also sharing my code with it.[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sorry, this is confusing. You say `Figure 1.1` shall appear in the list of tables?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `tocloft` package (`> texdoc tocloft` to see the manual). For example, after eliminating any typos:

```
\documentclass% ???
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newlength{\mylen} % a scratch length
\renewcommand{\cftfigpresnum}{Figure } % put Figure before figure number
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cftfigpresnum} % space for Figure text
\addtolength{\cftfignumwidth}{\mylen} % need more space for Figure + number
% and similarly for table entries
\renewcommand{\cfttabpresnum}{Table }
\settowidth{\mylen}{\cfttabpresnum}
\addtolength{\cfttabnumwidth}{\mylen}
% and whatever else for the rest of your document.
```

The manual explains the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion using package `tocbasic` with a standard class:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{tocbasic}[2018/12/30]
\DeclareTOCStyleEntries[
  indent=0pt,
  numsep=1em,
  dynnumwidth
]{tocline}{figure,table}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\figurename}
]{tocline}{figure}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\tablename}
]{tocline}{table}
\newcommand*\entryprefix[2]{#1 #2}

\begin{document}
\listoffigures
\chapter{Foo}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}
\caption{First Caption}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering\rule{5cm}{1cm}
\caption{Second Caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```